# How to create directory based on the username

Tags: php

I want to create a directory based on the username(user) that is logged in, to upload images to that folder, so when each user uploads an image file it will be sent to the directory based on the username and the image file is saved in that folder

```
$_SESSION["user"];
```

I use session to get the username, now I want to create a folder inside a folder name uploads

```
 mkdir('/uploads/' . $_SESSION['user']);
```

and make `$target_dir= location` for upload as above one.

Comment: mkdir( $path, 0777, true );

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh Those arguments are optional.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. If not, turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see the error message.

Comment: Error shows as
Warning mkdir no such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\page1.php

Comment: do you have "uploads" directory..?

Comment: Do you have a folder `/uploads` **in the root of your harddisk**? Probably not. Also, I think this is a bad idea, tying folder structures to users like this. Your file storage system should store files and your user information system should store user information. If you need to correlate those two, you can do that via database queries and URL rewrite rules as necessary...

Comment: yes i have created upload directory by myself
i would also like to know how to create a folder with in a folder using mkdir?

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, do you have a folder **`C:\uploads\ `**?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use of mkdir() and its parameter:**

recursive Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname. Defaults to FALSE.It means

**Path** : path of directory including directory name.

**Permission** : 0777

**Recursive Flag** : when you need to create subfolder.

```
$path = '/upload/UserA';
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

**Note**

/upload/ is almost certainly wrong. It points to the "upload" directory in the root directory, where you most likely don't have the permission to create one.

Comment: mkdir('\\xampp\\htdocs\\projectx\\uploads\\'.$username.'\\'.$counts, 0777, true);

I done it using this method..